# Using Google Maps API from Chrome App

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use Google maps inside of a Chrome App. Whenever I try to load the javascript I get the error:
`"Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Key&sensor=true'     because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'     chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src'     is used as a fallback."`

I thought about trying to use a webview or a sandbox, but am having issues implementing either. The sandbox has an issue because I also am doing a http request to a service with no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present.

Comment: Temporarily, I am using the static API inside of a webview. It "works" but is very undesireable.

Comment: May you post how exactly you are adding the script into your page?

Comment: Trying to load the external js I am just doing  `<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=true"></script>`

The webview I am doing that works with the static maps api is just 

`<webview id="map_canvas" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{map.center}}&zoom=16&size=400x600&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:red%7C{{map.center}}&sensor=true"></webview>`

Comment: 1. Add `"https://maps.googleapis.com/*"` to `permissions` in `manifest.json`.  Looking at `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=true`, its loading additional scripts using `document.write` which won't work in chrome apps.   What I did instead was to use [`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&callback=initialize`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&callback=initialize) which uses jsonp to call a js callback, and uses `document.createElement` to inject scripts asynchronously.  I'll see if I can find the docs..