# including google maps in chrome packages app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm getting really stuck trying to include Google Maps in my chrome packaged app. I'm getting a content security error, and I get why, but I just can't figure out how to 'safely' include the map.

My code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- libs js -->
    <script src="/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- js -->
    <script src="/js/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in custom.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // declare the map for use
    var map;

    // init function to set up the map
    function initialize() {
        var startCoords = [40.1234, -2.1234];
        mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(startCoords[0], startCoords[1]);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: mapCenter,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    };

    // init the map
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)

});
```

And this is my error:

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'
>   chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly
>   set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I've been reading about sandboxing and tried some things with that, but to no avail (is this the avenue to pursue?). I've also tried some tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601976/using-google-maps-api-from-chrome-app) but again, no joy. Any pointers or examples in code more than welcome. I've downloaded the [chrome-app samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples) from github but I can't see anything similar within the code to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external? That example creates an `<img>` element, but perhaps you could do the same with a `<script>` tag.

Comment: yes, thanks, this is where ive been referring to the sandbox content. Even when i sandbox the map and either embed in an iframe or load in a separate window it complains about not being able to use document.write, which I thought was the whole point of sandboxing.. confused.com

Comment: `document.write` is [not available in Chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated). You should look into embedding a `sandbox` page into your page if you want to load external resources.

Comment: I have sandboxed it but still complains about document.write .. ?

Comment: and it doesnt seem to like the inclusion of jquery?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the simillar issue.
Here is how I solved it.

Load the map inside a iframe in sandbox mode.

Use use the code from this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async) inside your iframe html, and replace the google map src "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&callback=initialize"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Asynchronous Loading</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

  function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&callback=initialize';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

window.onload = loadScript;

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

check out these two examples.  They may help you...

- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/sandbox
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/sandboxed-content

Both have a "main.html" with an < iframe >

That iframe points to a "sandbox.html" with "unsafe" content.

As prev poster said, be sure to check out this so your iframe will load right: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external